# How to execute ps1 script using docker run command?

Tags: powershell, docker, devops, powershell-core, docker-run

I need to use the official PowerShell Core Docker image to run a Docker container and make it execute a PowerShell script file.

I know it can be done using a Dockerfile and Docker build, but can't use that in this case.

From reading docs I came up with this, but it does not seem to work:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint "/tmp/test.ps1" repo/powershell:latest

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/tmp/test.ps1\": stat /tmp/test.ps1: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Error seems to say that it can't find the file but when running `stat "/tmp/test.ps1"` manually it works fine.

I feel like the binary `pwsh` should also be specified but can't find a way how to do it.

Comment: i usually run what inside of the docker like this:
`docker run -it repo/powershell:latest /tmp/test.ps`

and since you don't need to stay inside `-it` is not required

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Tried it but it gives the same error:

`docker run repo/powershell:latest /tmp/test.ps1
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/tmp/test.ps1\": stat /tmp/test.ps1: no such file or directory": unknown.`

Comment: Trying `stat` command afterwards: 

`rob@linuxvm:/tmp$ stat /tmp/test.ps1


  File: /tmp/test.ps1
  Size: 32              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 931983      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/     rob)   Gid: ( 1000/     rob)
Access: 2019-11-26 15:55:56.966119943 +0000
Modify: 2019-11-26 15:56:07.951610246 +0000
Change: 2019-11-26 15:56:07.951610246 +0000
 Birth: -`

Comment: just realized
`stat /tmp/test.ps1: no such file or directory`
powershell - means windows, and that means that  `/tmp/test.ps1` is not an absolute path from root. If so you should try something like `C:\bla\bla\another_bla\tmp\test.ps1`

Comment: I am using Ubuntu host with Docker. The PowerShell Core image is from Docker hub. And I believe the ps1 file is in the correct directory, new to Linux so maybe there's a mistake, but doing pwd in the dir returns /tmp/ so it's not /home/user/tmp or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`docker run -it  mcr.microsoft.com/powershell pwsh -c "Write-Host 'Hello, World'"`

this produces `Hello, World`

and `mcr.microsoft.com/powershell` is what google return as `official PowerShell Core Docker image`

this image doesn't have file `/tmp/test.ps1` inside. so not exactly clear what that image `repo/powershell:latest` have inside.

- if you are trying to read a file and execute inside of docker than this worked just fine for me:

```
docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/powershell pwsh -c $(cat test.ps)
```

- or, if you are trying to pass host file into the container and execute you can map local path to path inside of the container and than it would be:

```
docker run -v /tmp/localdata:/tmp/containerdata  -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/powershell pwsh /tmp/containerdata/test.ps
```

assuming that you have on host `/tmp/localdata` folder which contains `test.ps` file with `Write-Host 'Hello, World!'` text.

both ways result is `Hello, World`

Comment: Thank you! The last one with volumes did the trick, I was trying to pass a file from the host, sorry for the confusion caused, I assumed `--entrypoint` was meant to do exactly that. Somehow missed the part about Volumes in the docs.